# Java AWS S3: Why S3Object.ObjectMetadata.ContentMD5 is null while S3Object.ObjectMetadata.Etag is not null

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, md5

ContentMD5 of S3Object is coming as null. As per documentation it is null if it is not set. So question is how I can set it.

I am using pre signed url to upload data to S3 bucket and when I fetch the object the MD5Content is null. However E3Object is not null and holds the correct Hex encoded 128-bit Md5 value of the file that was uploaded. Also the pre signed url is set with header "content-md5" and the value is Base64 encoded MD5.

Code for creating pre signed url is:

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, key, httpMethod);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setContentType("image/jpeg");
byte[] resultByte = DigestUtils.md5(getImage());
String streamMD5 = new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(resultByte));
 generatePresignedUrlRequest.setContentMd5(streamMD5);
```

Code for obtaining data:

```
S3Object s3Object = getClient().getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key));
s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getETag(); //not null
s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentMD5(); // null
```

Answer (score 2):

The amazon while uploading data uses Base 64 MD5 while with download it use Hex MD5 which is part of  s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getETag()

Answer (score 0):

Presigned URLs are .. presigned URLs to consume later. Setting the md5 on a presigned URL does the following, [per documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.html#setContentMd5(java.lang.String)):

> Sets the expected content-md5 header of the request. This header value will be included when calculating the signature, and future requests must include the same content-md5 header value to access the presigned URL.

In order to change metadata on an *existing* s3 object, it must be copied. You can do something like this:

```
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata().setContentMD5(streamMD5);
CopyObjectRequest cor = new CopyObjectRequest(bucket, key, bucket, key);
getClient().copyObject(cor);
```

Finally, when you did this:

```
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setContentMd5(streamMD5);
```

All you've done is prepared a *request*. You need to then make the request:

```
PresignedUrl presignedUrl = getClient().generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The request using the presigned url is being made and it works fine but thing is later on when I am trying to fetch the object, the 3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentMD5() comes as null. So question is when presinged url is set with md5 content and object is uploaded using presigned url with md5 header then why fetching the object results in null contend m5.

Comment: @suchit that's because you aren't setting the MD5 when uploading the s3 object. Note etag is not the same as md5.

Comment: The following is the code for uploading the data to S3 using pre signed url. now is using the code if the upload is successful should not while fetching the object, md5 should not be null HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); connection.setDoOutput(true); connection.setDoInput(true); connection.setRequestMethod("PUT"); connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","image/jpeg"); connection.setRequestProperty("content-md5", getMd5()); OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream(); output.write(getImage()); output.flush();